# How does Amazon's Statistically Improbable Phrases work?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, platform-agnostic

How does something like Statistically Improbable Phrases work?

According to amazon:

> Amazon.com's Statistically Improbable
>   Phrases, or "SIPs", are the most
>   distinctive phrases in the text of
>   books in the Search Inside!™ program.
>   To identify SIPs, our computers scan
>   the text of all books in the Search
>   Inside! program. If they find a phrase
>   that occurs a large number of times in
>   a particular book relative to all
>   Search Inside! books, that phrase is a
>   SIP in that book.
>
> SIPs are not necessarily improbable
>   within a particular book, but they are
>   improbable relative to all books in
>   Search Inside!. For example, most SIPs
>   for a book on taxes are tax related.
>   But because we display SIPs in order
>   of their improbability score, the
>   first SIPs will be on tax topics that
>   this book mentions more often than
>   other tax books. For works of fiction,
>   SIPs tend to be distinctive word
>   combinations that often hint at
>   important plot elements.

For instance, for Joel's first book, the SIPs are: leaky abstractions, antialiased text, own dog food, bug count, daily builds, bug database, software schedules

One interesting complication is that these are phrases of either 2 or 3 words. This makes things a little more interesting because these phrases can overlap with or contain each other.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a lot like the way Lucene ranks documents for a given search query.  They use a metric called TF-IDF, where TF is term frequence and idf is inverse document frequency.  The former ranks a document higher the more the query terms appear in that document, and the latter ranks a document higher if it has terms from the query that appear infrequently across all documents.  The specific way they calculate it is log(number of documents / number of documents with the term) - ie, the inverse of the frequency that the term appears.

So in your example, those phrases are SIPs relative to Joel's book because they are rare phrases (appearing in few books) and they appear multiple times in his book.

**Edit**:  in response to the question about 2-grams and 3-grams, overlap doesn't matter.  Consider the sentence "my two dogs are brown".  Here, the list of 2-grams is ["my two", "two dogs", "dogs are", "are brown"], and the list of 3-grams is ["my two dogs", "two dogs are", "dogs are brown"].  As I mentioned in my comment, with overlap you get N-1 2-grams and N-2 3-grams for a stream of N words.  Because 2-grams can only equal other 2-grams and likewise for 3-grams, you can handle each of these cases separately.  When processing 2-grams, every "word" will be a 2-gram, etc.

Comment: it's a little trickier than that though, because phrases can be 2 or 3 words in length, which could overlap or contain each other. tf-idf is usually described with single terms only.

Comment: I'm not sure that matters so much, especially if its restricted to phrases of length 3 or less.  For a text stream of N tokens, you have N-1 bigrams and N-1 trigrams.  Of course, a bigram is only going to be equal to another bigram, and likewise for a trigram, so you could compute the IDF measures of bigrams and trigrams just as quickly as you could do it for words.

Comment: @ʞɔıu: It's usually described in single terms, but there's no need to apply it that way. That's why I mentioned 'a variation on' in my answer. danben's explanation covers it.

Comment: what about potential overlaps between the 2-grams and 3-grams? And will 2- and 3-grams need different idf thresholds?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  I'm happy to explain further, but I don't know what it is you don't get.

Answer (score 12):

They are probably using a variation on the [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) weight, detecting phrases that occur a high number of times in the specific book but few times in the whole corpus minus the specific book. Repeat for each book.

Thus 'improbability' is relative to the whole corpus and could be understood as 'uniqueness', or 'what makes a book unique compared to the rest of the library'.

Of course, I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 5):

As a starting point, I'd look at [Markov Chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

One option:

1. build a text corpus from the full index.
2. build a text corpus from just the one book.
3. for every m to n word phrase, find the probability that each corpus would generate it.
4. select the N phrases with the highest ratio of probabilities.

An interesting extension would be to run a Markov Chain generator where your weights table is a magnification of the difference between the global and local corpus. This would generate a "caricature" (literally) of the author's stylistic idiosyncrasies.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see how this compares to the lucene method above.

Comment: I suspect it might be equivalent if the corpus is built using a window at least as long as the phrases being considered.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for reviving an old thread, but I landed up here for the same question and found that there is some newer work which might add to the great thread.

I feel SIPs are more unique to a document than just words with high TF-IDF scores. For example, In a document about *Harry Potter*, terms like *Hermione Granger* and *Hogwarts* tend to be better SIPs where as terms like *magic* and *London* aren't. TF-IDF is not great at making this distinction.

I came across an interesting definition of SIPs [here](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/26/11/1453.full). In this work, the phrases are modelled as n-grams and their probability of occurrence in a document is computed to identify their uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly sure its the combination of SIPs that identify the book as unique. In your example its very rare almost impossible that another book has "leaky abstractions" and "own dog food" in the same book.

I am however making an assumption here as I do not know for sure.